# Passing parameters to nested component gives 'Error TS2322 Type is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I'm new to React and Typescript, so I'm having a problem I don't know how to approach.

I'm trying to nest a component inside another while passing a parameter from the parent to the child, but I can't figure out what this error is telling me.  The error is:

```
Error TS2322 (TS) Type '{ test: 10; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<B> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonl...'.
  Type '{ test: 10; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<BProps>>'.
    Property 'match' is missing in type '{ test: 10; }'.
```

It says "Readonly", but I don't see where read-only is coming from.

Here is component A, which I want to nest component B inside of:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import B from './B';

export default class A extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <B test={10} />;
    }
}
```

Here is component B.  I'm declaring test in BProps as a number, so I think it should work:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface BProps { test: number }
interface BState {  }

export default class B extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<BProps>, BState> {

    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<BProps>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            test: props.match.params.test
        };
    }

    public render() {
        return <h1>B</h1>;
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.  I started with the React & Redux project type and just added these two components to get the error.  I don't think the rest of the code matters, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The error says the props `RouteComponentProps<BProps>` has a `match` property as seen in `props.match.params.test`. Your wrapping props does not have that.

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean by wrapping props?

Comment: try: `export default class B extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}> & BProps, BState>`

Comment: That doesn't help.  I can say `test: props.test` in class B, but that's about it.

Comment: I think the problem is I copied and pasted the component code from a main page component that is being routed to, and then later decided against it and made it a subcomponent that no longer needs RouteComponentProps.  I removed RouteComponentProps from the definition of B and that fixed it.

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question and accepting that answer so others can see a correct example?